# How to change google token expiration time?

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm using google auth for authentication users via google and I read an expiration token param `exp` is in the seconds but when I had to try to convert this time to years and I get my token will expire after 50 years. 
I get information about this: [google token info](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library)
I using java library and get the following info:

```
GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
if (idToken != null) {
  Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

  // Print user identifier
  String userId = payload.getSubject();
  System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

  // Get profile information from payload
  String email = payload.getEmail();
  boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
  String name = (String) payload.get("name");
  String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
  String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
  String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
  String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
  Long expires = payload.payload.getExpirationTimeSeconds(); // this returns to me 1583167719 seconds.
```

Can I change the token expiration range?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "access_token": "XXXX", 
  "id_token": "XXX", 
  "expires_in": 3599, 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", 
  "refresh_token": "XXX"
}
```

The access token response should be 3600 which is one hour this is industry standard

3,600 Seconds = 60 Minutes = 60 Minutes

What the page you are linking address is the token verification which just verifies that an Id token is valid  For some reason this endpoint actually returns a unix time stamp (seconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC) of when the token will expire

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "117200475532672775346",
  "at_hash": "3UrVjh2VbWK-KYiElu2eiA",
  "name": "Linda Lawton",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20=s",
  "given_name": "Linda",
  "family_name": "Lawton",
  "locale": "en",
  "iat": "1583164112",
  "exp": "1583167712",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "17d55ff40991d6b0efd392b91a33e54c0e218b",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

[image]

### Can I change the token expiration range?

No token expiration is set up by the owner of the authorization server.